# Cannot Start MariaDB after Installing Fedora 27

Tags: mysql, mariadb, fedora-27

I have a problem which I cannot seem to solve. I am running Fedora 27 64 bit, and I have already installed httpd and PHP (I don't know if it makes a difference or not).

Basically, I am trying to install/enable/start MariaDB and/or MySQL.

I installed it via:`sudo dnf install mariadb mariadb-server`. It installed successfully, however when I tried to enable it with this: `sudo systemctl enable mariadb.service`, it said `Failed to enable unit: Unit file mariadb.service does not exist.`

I have tried using MySQL instead of mariadb as several threads recommended, however, I cannot seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

## EDIT

It turns out mariadb/mysql actually works anyway. I can log in through PHPMyAdmin and create/edit databases. I'm still not sure why I can't run `sudo systemctl enable mariadb` though.

Comment: So it looks like it didnt install successfully.

did you try `find`ing the mariadb.service file? Or perhaps verifying it installed correctly with `dnf list --installed`

Comment: It installed these packages: `mysql-community-client.x86_64              5.7.21-1.fc27               @mysql57-community
mysql-community-common.x86_64              5.7.21-1.fc27               @mysql57-community
mysql-community-devel.x86_64               5.7.21-1.fc27               @mysql57-community
mysql-community-libs.x86_64                5.7.21-1.fc27               @mysql57-community
mysql-community-server.x86_64              5.7.21-1.fc27               @mysql57-community
` Not sure if those are the right ones or not...

Comment: Did you try with just `sudo systemctl start mariadb` and `sudo systemctl enable mariadb`